# How can I stream a movie in iOS and playback from the filesystem later?

Tags: ios

I've got an app that currently ships with all the videos it can play embedded in it. This doesn't scale well, and unless you want to play all the movies, wastes disk space. It also makes it less desirable to upgrade the app because you have to re-download all movies.

What I would like to do is download the movie on the fly, play it back while downloading, and then if it's successfully downloaded, save it to the file system so that next time they want to watch it, it streams from the local file.

I can do whatever is needed to the video, but currently I'm serving it up as an .mp4 file from Amazon S3, with a mimetype of video/mp4, and so the first half of my issue works fine: the movie downloads, and MPMovieViewController will start playing it as soon as it thinks it has downloaded "enough."

Is there any way to tap into the cache of that video file so that I can save it and control how long it resides on the filesystem? This seems like it would be the easiest approach.

I am targeting iOS 5+6, but if the only solution available required iOS 6, I would consider it also. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Using AFNetworking, I am now half-way there, I think. I am downloading the video file from the server, and listening for the download progress. Once I see 25% of the video has been downloaded, I start playback on the local file using an MPMoviePlayerController.

The main issue I'm running into now is playback seems to get screwed up. It's going along fine, 25% downloaded, playback starts... download continues normally... then the file finishes downloading completely, and shortly thereafter video freezes. The onscreen playback timer still indicates playback is ongoing and I don't see any "playback finished" type notifications, but the video is frozen. My guess based on the behavior is that perhaps the initial buffer for the video playback was used up, and it isn't detecting that more video is available on disk now?

Is there any way to interact with MPMoviePlayerController to let it know periodically to refresh the buffer it's playing out of? Or some other way to handle this situation?

Comment: Does it have to be a `MPMovieViewController`? Sounds like your problem can be easily solved using `AVFoundation` and `NSURLConnection`

Comment: Oh no, definitely no requirements on how it's done. I'm new to iOS and MPMovieViewController was the only thing I'd found so far. Can you share some insights on how to use those two to do this? BTW, I'm also using AFNetworking in my app for other things, so I can utilize that if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as of iOS 10 with [`AVAssetDownloadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetdownloadtask?language=objc). See [this WWDC 2016 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/504) and [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams?language=objc).

Alternatively, if your movie isn't DRM'd, you can do it with [AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloaderdelegate?language=objc), which effectively lets you give an `AVPlayer` an arbitrary stream of bytes. See [this walkthrough](https://jaredsinclair.com/2016/09/03/implementing-avassetresourceload.html).

Comment: this documentation and this walkthrough links are broken

Comment: @KamenDobrev try it now?

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE: Make sure to see the newer answer from @TomHamming.**

I have yet to find a conclusive answer, but at this time I believe the answer is: you can't reliably do this. At least not without a lot of work which seems too much like a hack. I filed a feature request with Apple as it really seems like this should be possible with some adjustments to MPMoviePlayerController.

I will go over the variety of things I tried or considered, and the results I encountered.

- **Pass MPMoviePlayerController a URL to your movie file, which allows it to stream, and then pull the file out of the cache it was saved into, into your local Documents folder.** Won't work, as of iOS 6. I filed a feature request with Apple, but as it stands now there's no way to get your hands on the file they are downloading, AFAIK.
- **Start downloading the movie file with NSURLConnection (or something like AFNetwork), and then when a "decent amount" has been downloaded to the device, pass the file URL to the MPMoviePlayerController and let it stream from disk.** Sort of works, but not well. Three problems:

  - It's really hard to know when to start playing the file. I haven't figured out the algorithm Apple uses, and so I always erred on the side of caution, waiting for 25% to be downloaded before playing.
  - The MPMoviePlayerController interface provides no sense of the movie being streamed, as it does when Apple is doing the calculations via the network. It appears to the user that the file is totally downloaded when it really is not.
  - And most importantly, MPMoviePlayerController seems to not work well with playing a file that is not completely downloaded. I experienced playback problems once the file finished downloading, or if the player caught up with the amount downloaded, and never found a graceful way to handle these situations.
- **Same procedure as above, but use AVFoundation classes to more finely control the playback process, and avoid the issues described above regarding playback stopping, etc.** Might work, but I want all the features of MPMoviePlayerController. Re-implementing MPMoviePlayerController myself just to get this one feature seems like a waste of time.
- **Same procedure as #1 above, but run a small web server in your app to handle streaming the video from the disk to MPMoviePlayerController**, with the hope being that the streaming would work more like it normally does when streaming the file directly from an external web server. Works, but results were still sporadic and performance seemed to suffer. I did my test with [CocoaHTTP](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer). I decided against this approach because it just felt like a terrible hack.
- **Run a lightweight HTTP proxy, thus intercepting the downloaded movie file data as it gets streamed from the internet into your MPMoviePlayerController.** Not sure if this works or not. I was not able to test this yet, as I have not found a lightweight HTTP proxy written in Objective-C, and at this point don't feel like implementing one just to try this experiment. It seems like the next easiest of all these hacks to implement -- if you don't have to write the proxy!

At this point I've decided to go the less-hacky, but also less user-friendly route of simply downloading the file completely, and then passing it to MPMoviePlayerController, until a better solution comes along.

Comment: I was going to suggest the 'small web server' approach.  It doesn't sound like a terrible hack, just a facade to serve the player in the manner it expects.  Only other angle I would have looked at was perhaps looking into the possibility of creating some kind of place holder file of the correct size at the beginning and then filling the file in with the real data as it is downloaded. Not sure if this is possible or would fix anything, just wondering if it maybe due to a changing file size?  Good thorough answer by the way.

Comment: I am currently using the internal http proxy to handle the playback and intercept the chunks of data. A problem with this is that MPMoviePlayerController uses HLS protocol and thus, asks for different parts of the file on each request. So you must have a ligthweitgh proxy that handles Partial Content as MPMoviePlayerCOntroller will stop if not given what asked. I am facing a problem on playing from file. On Streaming, I can handle the requests just fine, but on playing from file, the MPMoviePLayerController keeps asking me for icy-metadata: 1. Has this happened to you already?

Comment: For iOS7, is this now possible? I've been going through the docs, but haven't found anything that would suggest this is an option. It still appears as an either/or (stream or DL).